# Psycopg2 not raising no results to fetch error

Tags: python, json, pyramid, psycopg2

I have the following code:

```
def execute_statement(stmt):
    #create connection
    conn = psdb.connect(dbname='db', user='user', host='localhost', password='password')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(stmt)
    rows=cur.fetchall()[0]
    conn.close()
    return rows

def get_product_details(request):
     """Retrieve all information for a certain product, -> returns id, name, description and price"""

     #initiate faultstring
     faultstring = None

     #get product information from db
     try:
        row = execute_statement("""SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(pr)) FROM (SELECT id, name, description, price FROM product WHERE product.id = %(product_id)s) pr""" % request.matchdict)[0]
     except Exception as e:
         faultstring = str(e)

     #create responseobject
     resp = {}
     if faultstring:
         resp['faultstring'] = faultstring
     else:
         resp['product'] = row

     respjson = json.dumps(resp)
     return Response(json_body=json.loads(respjson))
```

Route:

```
 #get_product_details
 config.add_route('getproductdetail', '/getproductdetail/{product_id}')
 config.add_view(get_product_details, route_name='getproductdetail', renderer='json')
```

The try/except block in `get_product_details()` returns a faultstring if I fill in a letter as an ID (ex: `localhost/get_product_details/q`)

If I try to get a product which does not exist, like `localhost/get_product_details/500` it does not fill the faultstring, and returns `'products': null` while the error does exist. Why doesnt it handle the exception for an empty fetch the same way as it does with a faulty datatype?